# Showing that the standard topology is a subset of the topology generated by the collection $\{[x, y]: x \text{ rational}, y \text{ irrational}, x<y\}$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $C = \{[x, y]\mid x \in \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}, x < y\}$. Suppose that it is shown that $C$ is a basis for some topology $\mathcal{T}$ of $\mathbb{R}$. I have to prove that the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$ is a subset of $\mathcal{T}$, where the standard topology $\mathcal{T}_{\text{standard}}$ is characterized by $U \in \mathcal{T}$ iff $\forall x \in U:\exists r > 0: (x - r, x + r) \subset U$. It could be that I've misunderstood for what it means for a topology $A$ to be a subset of a topology $B$, but as I've understood it it means that any set of $\mathcal{T}_{\text{standard}}$ can be spanned by the basic elements (= elements of the basis) of $\mathcal{T}$. And I really don't understand how any open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ can be represented by unions/intersections of certain *closed* intervals of $\mathbb{R}$, in the standard topology.

Comment: Hint: Try, as an exercise, to compute the union:$$\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb{N}} \left[-1 + \frac{1}{n}, 1 - \frac{1}{n}\right].$$It's an interval. What are its endpoints? Does the union contain them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x,r\in\Bbb R$, with $r>0$, take two sequences $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $(x-r,x+r)$ such that, for each $n\in\Bbb N$:

- $x_n\leqslant y_n$;
- $x_n\in\Bbb Q$;
- $y_n\notin\Bbb Q$;

and that

- $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x-r$;
- $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=x+r$.

Then $(x-r,x+r)=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}[x_n,y_n]\in\mathcal T$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be standard open and $x \in U$ arbitrary. It follows that for some $r>0$ we have $(x-r,x+r) \subseteq U$. Let $q_x$ be be rational number in $(x-r,x)$ and $s_x$ be an irrational number in $(x,x+r)$, which is possible since both the rationals and irrationals are order dense in $\Bbb R$.
Then $x \in [q_x,s_x]\in \mathcal{C}$ and $[q_x,s_x] \subseteq (x-r,x+r) \subseteq U$ so that $U$ is open in the topology generated by $\mathcal{C}$.

So $\mathcal{T}_{\text{standard}} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$. That's all there is to it.